# PHP chaining callback functions

Tags: php, anonymous-function

I've encountered this code, but I can't understand its logic. Could someone explain why the output is the way it is?

```php
<?php

$functions = [
    
    function($next) {
        
        echo 'A' .PHP_EOL;
        $next();
    },
    
    function($next) {
        
        echo 'B' .PHP_EOL;
        $next();
    },
    
    function($next) {
        
        echo 'C' .PHP_EOL;
        $next();
    }
    
];
    
$a = function() {
    
    echo 'Main Content' .PHP_EOL;
     
};

foreach($functions as $function) {
    
    $a = fn() => $function($a);
    
}

$a();
```

Output:

C
B
A
Main Content

Answer (score 2):

The code you provided looks like from some middleware, wherein the outer function must utilize the result of inner function to perform some task

For simplicity sake I have converted the 3 iterations of the foreach loop into an equivalent code

Now when the loop starts, on its 1st iteration it will be something like
(For better clarity I used the "full-form" of anonymous function instead of the shorthand notation)

```
$firstLoopFn = function($next) {
    echo 'A' .PHP_EOL;
    $next(); // <-- the origin $a function("Main Content") which does not call any other function
}
```

`$firstLoopFn` becomes the new `$a` in your original code

What happens in the 2nd iteration? Same

```
$secondLoopFn = function($next) {   
    echo 'B' .PHP_EOL;
    $next();  // <-- this is actually $firstLoopFn
}
```

`$secondLoopFn` becomes the new `$a` in your original code

Similarly the 3rd iteration

```
$thirdLoopFn = function($next) {   
    echo 'C' .PHP_EOL;
    $next();  // <-- this is actually $secondLoopFn
}
```

`$thirdLoopFn` becomes the new `$a` in your original code

Now the order, it is nothing but similar to this

```
$result = Function3rd( Function2d( Function1st( ... ) ) )
```

`Function3rd` will run first the then `Function2d` and so on

Please observe in your case **the last iteration of foreach loop** adds the **final "layer"** so it gets runs first (Function3rd here)

Also the fact that `echo` **precedes** the call to inner function in the source code so it gets run before the inner function called, to simply say function prints first then calls the inner function

```
    thirdLoopFn( /*echo C */ 
        secondLoopFn(  /*echo B */ 
            firstLoopFn( /*echo A */ $a)
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a kind of reversed invocation, the code snippet is setting an initial callback function `line 18` and then looping over the `$functions` array, overriding the old variable `$a` by the new function in the loop. At the end, the last function (the one with `echo 'C' .PHP_EOL;`) is being called, causing an initial call to the `$next()` callback `line 14`, which is - from the foreach loop - points to the `b` function, which is being called, causing the invocation of the `$next()` callback `line 10` and so on. Until it reaches the initial function declaration.